# getCookie in OmniFaces?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I found out that I can generate Cookies with Omnifaces, like:

```
    public void addCookie(String cookieName, String cookieValue) throws IOException {
            Faces.addResponseCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, "https://myurl.com", "/", -1);
        Faces.refresh();
}
```

As far I understood I can GET also the Cookie, like:

```
public String findCookie(String cookieName) throws IOException {

            String cookieValue = Faces.getRequestCookie(cookieName);
            return cookieValue;

    }
```

But what is unclear for me: 
In findCookie(): for what should I search, because in create method I have also the page name included?
I´m missing in **Faces.getRequestCookie(cookieName)** the application name, like:
Faces.getRequestCookie(cookieName, applicationName);

Or should I save the cookieName, like:
**String myCookie = "myPageName" + "myCookie";**
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you **try** with just the `cookieName` like the api states? It is always good to learn the basics of web development (http, html, css, javascript) since JSF builds on top of those. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+do+http+cookies+work+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: You SET cookies for a certain path (or even domain). Whether the cookie gets sent back by the browser depends on the page (and/or domain) that is requested (http get and/or post). You cannot actively 'retrieve' cookies. They are there or they are not.

Comment: This question is confusing. It's in first place indeed impossible to obtain cookies for a different (relative) domain/path than the current one. This has nothing to do with JSF. It's just a basic HTTP rule.